# Using REST-Assured's ifValidationFails together with JSONAssert

Tags: json, rest, unit-testing, rest-assured, jsonassert

I decided to use [REST-Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) for testing REST services. The results are (mostly) JSON and XML documents. For checking JSON, I find [JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) very helpful.

I do not want to compare parts of the body, but the **complete** body of a response. So, the [examples at REST-Assured's documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-example) are not very helpful, as they extract parts of the response body.

Currently, I am extracting the body and compare the body afterwards:

```
public void assertGet(String restURL, String fileName) throws Exception {
    String expectedStr = readFromClasspath(fileName);
    final String receivedStr = given()
            .log()
            .ifValidationFails()()
            .accept(getAccept(fileName))
            .get(callURL(restURL))
            .then()
            .log()
            .ifValidationFails()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .response()
            .getBody()
            .asString();
    if (isXml(fileName)) {
        org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(receivedStr, CompareMatcher.isIdenticalTo(expectedStr).ignoreWhitespace());
    } else {
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(
                expectedStr,
                receivedStr,
                true);
    }
}
```

The issue is that `ifValidationFails()` does not make any sense, because `asString()` is always successful.

Now I wonder how I can include the `JSONAssert.assertEquals` and Hamcrest's `assertThat` into the `given()` method of REST-Assured to enable logging on failing validation.

Full source is available at [Eclipse Winery's repository](https://github.com/eclipse/winery/blob/ab4bf84bc0b14e274d863db1675184b48fc0388c/org.eclipse.winery.repository/src/test/java/org/eclipse/winery/repository/resources/AbstractResourceTest.java#L108).